# How to calculate "time until" a certain date using PHP and the Zend Framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework, date

I have two Zend Date objects to work with:

```
$now = Zend_Date::now();
$sessionStart = new Zend_Date('2010-04-01 10:00:00', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');
```

I need to calculate the time remaining and display in a human readable manner.

```
The session will begin in 7 days.
The session will begin in 30 minutes.
```

How can I do this with PHP and the Zend Framework?

### Solution

Here's what I came up with. If you've got a better solution, please post it.

```
$remainingSeconds = $sessionStart->getTimestamp() - $now->getTimestamp();
// or: $remainingSeconds = $sessionStart->sub($now);
$remainingMinutes = $remainingSeconds / 60;

if ($remainingMinutes < 0) {
    //session is in the past
    return '0 days';
}

if (floor($remainingMinutes) <= 1) {
    return '1 minute';
}

if (floor($remainingMinutes) < 60) {
    return floor($remainingMinutes) . ' minutes';
}

$remainingHours = $remainingMinutes / 60;

if (floor($remainingHours) <= 1) {
    return '1 hours';
}

if (floor($remainingHours) < 24) {
    return floor($remainingHours) . ' hours';
}

$remainingDays = $remainingHours / 24;

if (floor($remainingDays) <= 1) {
    return '1 day';
}
return floor($remainingDays) . ' days';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.date.overview.html) describes this pretty good:

> The methods add(), sub(), compare(), get(), and set() operate generically on dates. In each case, the operation is performed on the date held in the instance object. The $date operand is required for all of these methods, except get(), and may be a Zend_Date instance object, a numeric string, or an integer.

So:

```
$sessionStart->sub($now);
```

should do it.

How to customize the output is described in [this section](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.date.constants.html#zend.date.constants.selfdefinedformats).

**Update:**
Here is an example I found on the [internet](http://cmorrell.com/web-development/calculating-the-difference-in-days-between-two-zend_date-objects-373):

```
$jan1 = new Zend_Date('1.12.2009', Zend_Date::DATES);
echo "\nJanuary first: ", $jan1->toString();

$christmas = new Zend_Date('25.12.2009', Zend_Date::DATES);
echo "\nChristmas is on: ", $christmas->toString();

$diff = $christmas->sub($jan1);
echo "\nNumber of days: ", $diff / 60 / 60 / 24;
```

On this site, the comment also states:

> The sub() method returns the milliseconds difference between the receiver and the argument dates